# Proper pattern to use when sharing large amounts of code and a similar control flow?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, patterns-and-practices

So I'm currently building an application that allows a user to fill out paperwork digitally, and then that information is taken in by the server and a PDF is populated and returned to the user.

The internal logic for each page is pretty similar:

1. Receive `Request` from client
2. Open proper PDF template from file system
3. Iterate over the properties of the received `Request` using reflection

   1. Check if the property contains a `PDFFieldName` attribute.
   2. If attribute is found, populate the matching PDF field from the `Request` property.
4. Flatten PDF
5. Return PDF to user.

In this control flow, we assume that each incoming request is serialized into a proper pre-created request class. The request classes match the post-data coming back from the client, and if necessary contain properties that compute the proper values for the PDF.

The only portions of the process that vary considerably are:

- The file system path for the file.
- The type of class serializing the data.
- The outputted filename.

Aside from this, there are very few differences between each process (although there may be some). What code pattern would prevent the most code reuse, and be most adequate for the given scenario?

**EDIT**

Here is a code example of what I'm currently doing:

```
// PDF Generation Code
public byte[] GeneratePDF(string path, object response)
{
    var pdfTemplate = path;
    var pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdfTemplate);
    var newPdf = new MemoryStream();
    var pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, newPdf);

    try
    {
        var pdfFormFields = pdfStamper.AcroFields;
        pdfFormFields.SetField("Date", DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"));
        var properties = response.GetType().GetProperties();
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
        {
            var attr = (PDFFieldName)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(property, typeof(PDFFieldName));
            if (attr != null)
            {
                pdfFormFields.SetField(attr.Name, property.GetValue(response)?.ToString() ?? "");
            }
        }

        pdfStamper.FormFlattening = true;

        pdfStamper.Close();
        newPdf.Flush();

        return newPdf.ToArray();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
    }
    finally
    {
        pdfStamper.Dispose();
        pdfReader.Close();
        pdfReader.Dispose();
        newPdf.Close();
        newPdf.Dispose();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Example response class:

```
public class ShareInfoResponse
{
    [PDFFieldName("Name1")]
    public string name1 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Name2")]
    public string name2 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Name3")]
    public string name3 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Name4")]
    public string name4 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Name5")]
    public string name5 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Name6")]
    public string name6 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Relationship1")]
    public string relationship1 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Relationship2")]
    public string relationship2 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Relationship3")]
    public string relationship3 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Relationship4")]
    public string relationship4 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Relationship5")]
    public string relationship5 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("Relationship6")]
    public string relationship6 { get; set; }
    [PDFFieldName("SSN")]
    public string ssn { get; set; }

}
```

Example MVC controller:

```
public IActionResult ShareMedicalInfo(ShareInfoResponse response)
{
    var path = _appEnvironment.ApplicationBasePath + @"\wwwroot\forms\";
    const string file = "Authorization_to Share_Information.pdf";

    return new FileContentResult(GeneratePDF(path + file, response), "application/pdf")
    {
        FileDownloadName = "Authorization_to Share_Information.pdf"
    };
}
```

Comment: Could you post an example of your current architecture? because it seems to me that Inheritance and Solid principles are enough, remember that design patterns are intended to solve specific problems.

Comment: Also if you are looking for a known property on the request I would question the need to use reflection.  Can you not define a data contract for the request object and provide methods for serialization, deserialization, validation, and access to the PDFFieldName value?  You could isolate this contract into a separate library to be consumed by third parties as well.

Comment: @J.Pichardo I've added an example.

Comment: To expand on what @J.Pichardo said, if you have several different types of PDF files to generate, I would definitely recommend using Inheritance with a generic base class. All of the common code can be in those abstract generic base classes, and anything specific to a type can be in the specific derivations on each step.

Comment: @krillgar the method by which is currently works is by simply passing in the response object and the name of the PDF. It determines the values for the PDF based off of the response class type. If any of the values need to be manipulated, I do it using a custom `get` setter.  The actual population logic is identical, the other difference are the fields contained in each PDF.

Comment: You don't even need inheritance. One class (or set of classes) can handle all the different cases and PDF files. You don't even need the different classes for serialization. You just have to use properties, files, etc to configure the instances before your operation begins.

Comment: That's what the above code does somewhat. Each request has a unique class that templates out each field. I was just checking if there was a better way.

Comment: @Jdsfighter Maybe I'm wrong, but seems to me that what you are looking for is the [Template Pattern](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern).

Comment: `we assume that each incoming request is serialized into a proper pre-created request class` If that is the case, then why are you using reflection to check if a given property exists?